# Last digit of partial sum of Fibonacci series

Tags: c++, math, fibonacci

I'm trying to find the last digit of the sum of the fibonacci series from a starting to an end point. As we find the last digit using `%10` , Fibonnaci will repeat it's last digit sequence every 60 times - using the **Pisano Series**

My attempt at the solution:

We find the last digits of the first 60 digits, store them in an array and then continuously loop over and sum over the digits starting from n%60 to m. We then finally modulo 10 the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int fibonacci_fast(long long n,long long m) {
    // write your code here
    long long a[60];
    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=1;
    long long sum=0;
    for(long long i=2;i<60;i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1]+a[i-2];
        a[i] = a[i] % 10;
    }
    int j=0;
    int p=1;
    int c=0;
    for(int i=n%60;;i++)
    {
        if(i==60)
        {
            i=i%60;
        }
        sum=sum+a[i];
        c=c+1;
        if(c==m)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return sum%10;
}

int main() {
    long long from, to;
    std::cin >> from >> to;
    std::cout << fibonacci_fast(from, to) << '\n';
}
```

The major issue I'm having with this current code is that for lower values, it works fine, but if I input higher values such as 0 to 239, It only works when the condition changes to `if(c+1)==m` which then results in the smaller values solutions turning wrong.

The c counter works correctly though and goes up to 239 but I still cannot figure out the issue with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int fibonacci_fast(long long n,long long m) {
    // write your code here
    long long a[60];
    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=1;
    long long sum=0;
    sum = a[0] + a[1];
    for(long long i=2;i<60;i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1]+a[i-2];
        a[i] = a[i] % 10;
        sum = (sum + a[i]) % 10;
    }
    int x = (m - n + 1)/60;
    sum = (sum * x) % 10;
    int i = n + 60 * x;
    while(i <= m)
    {
        sum = (sum + a[i%60]) % 10;
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    long long from, to;
    std::cin >> from >> to;
    std::cout << fibonacci_fast(from, to) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I have created a new optimized code for you! Please upvote/accept my answer(s) if you find them useful. If you need any further explanation for the above code, I can provide you with that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the variable **c** to be equal to the value of **n** and not 0 (zero)
`int c = n;`

Also, please clear the concept whether you want to include the index m or not.
Example, if user enters: 
`n -> 10`
`m -> 20`
Then your code provided above will add the last digit values of the Fibonacci numbers from the index 10 to the index 19 only. So please clear this doubt of mine, then I will add further.

Comment: We're treating 0 as the first number here, and we want it to be inclusive of both

Comment: Your c initialization fixed the program but can it be optimized further ?. It seems to stop at very big inputs

Comment: I have created a new optimized code for you! Please upvote/accept my answer(s) if you find them useful. If you need any explanation for the code, I can provide you with that!